# Mustache.js vs Mustache.net. What is faster?

Tags: asp.net, .net, mustache

I'm developing a web-site with ASP.NET 4.0. Some pages need to get data from the server via AJAX requests (for instance, a list of items, sorted or/and filtered by a parameter). And there I can see two options for templating:
1) AJAX handler get data from database and templates it with Mustache. Returns html code ready to display to the end user.
2) AJAX handler get data from database and sends it as JSON. Javascript code formats data with Mustache on the client-side.

My question is what will perform faster?

Comment: Dan-o, what a nice solution =)

Comment: @maxibrain if you would read http://stackoverflow.com/about you would see that in the section "Don't ask about..." it's an entry which says "Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)" that's what Dan-o is trying to say...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your question can be answered without testing, but I'm not sure the difference would be really significant. However, raw speed notwithstanding, I would go probably for option 2:

- HTTP traffic will certainly be lighter with your JSON-formatted data rather than a complete HTML output (this is generally better),
- The data can still be handled dynamically on the client side

If your website is designed as a "web application", with an emphasis on client-side processing, this is the way to go. But on the other hand, if you think of your output as something mainly static, it is probably simpler to keep all the work on the server side.